# WebApi causes 404 with action parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

For a few months now, I've been using a method that looks like this:

```
    <HttpGet>
    <HttpPost>
    Function MyMethod(MyParam as Integer) As HttpResponseMessage
        'return data here
    End Function
```

It was working fine. But suddenly, and I can't see that anything has changed, I'm getting this error:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://domain/api/MyController/MyMethod'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'MyController' that matches the request."}
```

What really puzzles me is that while debugging, I removed the parameter, so the method looks like this:

```
<HttpGet>
<HttpPost>
Function MyMethod() As HttpResponseMessage
  'return data here
End Function
```

and this does NOT cause the 404, *even though the method is exactly the same*. What's going on here?!

**Update**: I made the parameter optional, and then the method IS called, but the parameter is not passed, and instead uses the default. So the problem seems to be the way that I'm passing the parameter. I'm using jQuery `$.post` to send the request, and according to Fiddler, this is the packet being sent:

```
POST MyDomain/api/MyController/MyMethod HTTP/1.1
Host: MyDomain
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 12
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

MyParam=123
```

This looks correct to me, but WebApi doesn't recognize that parameter.

**Update 2**: My jQuery call looks like this:

```
$.post(url, postData)
    .done(function (data)
         {
             //do something on success
         })
        .fail(function (data)
        {
             //do something on failure
        });
```

If I change the `post` to `get`, it works fine. So it's got something to do with with (1) the way jQuery is sending the parameter, which I doubt, since the Fiddler trace looks fine; or (2) the way WebApi model binding is unpacking the request.

Comment: Something must have changed, it cannot start failing out of nowhere. Have you changed the routing or something else?

Comment: It must be that your client code was somehow modified to NOT supply the `MyParam` parameter. The second `MyMethod` is NOT exactly the same as the first `MyMethod`, because it no longer accepts a parameter, thus changing the method signature.

Comment: @djikay: I think this is likely, because I've just tried making the parameter optional, and then the method IS called, but the value that I'm passing isn't passed, and the default value is used instead. So now I think it's a bug in my jQuery post call. Still not seeing what the bug is though.

Comment: In your jQuery `url`, you need to add a "query parameter", something like this: `url: "api/My/MyMethod?MyParam=" + 42` or something along these lines (I don't know jQuery very well). Also, note that I specified the name of the controller as `My` and not as `MyController`. That's because it's a ASP.NET Web API convention that controllers are referenced in URLs with their name before the word "Controller". Take another look at your client and see if any of what I said helps.

Comment: @djikay: The controller name is right; I just called it that here to make it clear what the different pieces are. I can't append to the query string like that, because the method is `HttpPost`, not `HttpGet`.

Comment: OK. Are you sure the parameter is called `MyParam` in the method definition? You need to use the actual name in the method. Also, try sending it as JSON in your request body, e.g. `"MyParam":123` or something like that. Another thing is it might be worth denoting your `MyMethod`'s parameter as `[FromBody]` to tell the Web API when to get the parameter. I know that for a POST it *by default* looks in the body anyway, but just in case. Finally, you can append to the query string like that IF you specify `[FromUri]`, but let's not worry about that for now.

Comment: @djikay: I tried this and the result surprised me: now I don't get a 404, but the value of the parameter is 0. So now it can find the method, but it's losing the value of the parameter.

Comment: I've added an answer to summarise our discussion so far and keep it in one place. I've added some sample jQuery at the end that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be that your client code was somehow modified to NOT supply the `MyParam` parameter. The second `MyMethod` is NOT exactly the same as the first `MyMethod`, because it no longer accepts a parameter, thus changing the method signature. This must be the reason why the request succeeds when you remove the parameter -- your client is not sending it in the first place.

In your jQuery `url`, you need to add a "query parameter", something like this:

```
url: "api/My/MyMethod?MyParam=" + 42
```

or something along these lines (I don't know jQuery very well).

After reading your comments regarding passing the parameter in the body, are you sure the parameter is called `MyParam` in the method definition? You need to use the actual name in the method.

Also, try sending it as JSON in your request body, e.g. `"MyParam":123` or `"MyParam":"123"` (something like that).

As Toan said in his answer, you must denote your `MyMethod`'s parameter with the `[FromBody]` attribute to tell the Web API where to find the parameter, i.e.:

```
Function MyMethod([FromBody]MyParam as Integer) As HttpResponseMessage
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since your parameter is a "simple" type, if you don't add the `[FromBody]` attribute, then the behaviour you're seeing can be explained. The Web API is looking for an "optional" (as you specified) parameter in the URL as a query parameter (yes, you can have those for Post methods as well as for Get ones). It doesn't find it there but the route still matches, so it continues and uses a default value of 0 for it. Now when you add the `[FromBody]` parameter, Web API will look for it in the body of the request instead of expecting it to be in the URL as a query parameter and the binding should now work as expected.

See this article where it explains about parameter binding: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

By the way, you can actually append to the query string like that IF you specify `[FromUri]`, but let's not worry about that for now.

Looking at your second edit, it's not exactly clear what the jQuery syntax looks like, especially with regards to passing the parameter. You should probably try something like this:

```
$.post(url, { "MyParam":123 })
    .done(function (data) {
        //do something on success
    })
    .fail(function (data)
    {
        //do something on failure
    });
```

As I said, my jQuery isn't great (I'm trying!), but something along these lines should work (I'm a bit unclear on whether `"`s are required around `MyParam`). In particular, notice how the `MyParam` is being passed in (the equivalent to your `postData`).

Finally, I found this interesting article about [POSTing primitive parameters to Web API](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/) that might help you with the jQuery POST operation. It contains both jQuery snippets and explanation about `[FromBody]` and how it should all fit together.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Thank you so much! Also, here's another link worth mentioning directly: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx. It's linked to in one of the articles you mentioned, and was helpful in understanding parameter binding in WebApi.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: That's good stuff, you are very welcome! I'm glad we got there in the end. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

You must mask your parameter is from the body of the request in order to get it work using **[FromBody]** attribute.

Therefore,
Change

```
 Function MyMethod(MyParam as Integer) As HttpResponseMessage
        'return data here
    End Function
```

To

```
 Function MyMethod([FromBody]MyParam as Integer) As HttpResponseMessage
        'return data here
   End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Download/open Fiddler and generate the error with your original code.  When looking at that 404 error in fiddler you will most probably find that DJikay is correct.

Comment: I did this and updated my question with the Fiddler trace data. The request looks right to me.

Comment: What is MessageDetail, that it is referring too in the error?

Comment: @SteveNewton: That's just an additional error detail.